# Create many transactions for one table in GeneXus

Tags: genexus

I'm having a trouble with a GeneXus' Transaction object.

I want to create two Transactions to an Informix table.

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do a dataview over a existing database you can see how to do here http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?6627

If you want to create two transactions over the same table you can see the parallel transaction concept here
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?20209

Answer (score 0):

If two transactions share the same key, they are considered "parallel transactions". To put it bluntly, there are 2 transactions that refer to the same db table.